# NextJS Clerk Private Routes not working after deployment using Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, clerk

I am trying to build a simple NextJS app that uses Clerk for Auth. Locally, everything works as it should, but when I deploy using Vercel, private routes all redirect to the home page, even after the user is logged in / authenticated. My auth middleware is basically default:

```js
import { authMiddleware, redirectToSignIn }    from "@clerk/nextjs";
    
export default authMiddleware({
    publicRoutes: ["/", "/dashboard"], 
    authorizedParties: ["https://custom.vercel.app", "http://localhost:3000"]
});
    
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};
```

and "/", "/dashboard", and "/feed" routes are all built the same way, just returning simple divs. I have Vercel set up with the following ENV Variables (specified for production/dev when necessary):

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_testxxx / pk_livexxx
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=sk_testxxx / sk_livexxx

NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL=/sign-up
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=/
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/
```

here is the file tree:
[filetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m8Rl.png)

I tried to write a custom afterAuth function but this ended with the same issue - private routes work locally, do not work after vercel deployment